# AWK: Forcing/Casting Uninitialized Variable as type "array" rather than "numeric-string"

Tags: arrays, recursion, awk

Figuring out the AWK recursion puzzle.

I have a recursive task where I have to fill in an array.  However, I must pass the array first as just a parameter.  The recursion fills in the array.  In order to do that, the recursive calls need to know the length of the array, so they can add to the end of the array.

The only problem is that I cant fill in the first element of the array after I run a function on the parameter--both `length()` and `isarray()` run on an unknown parameter seem to force it to be of scalar type.

So I need some way to know if I am adding to the array for the first time, before I use length.  I would rather not pass an extra parameter that records the depth of the recursion, and tells the code when the array is going to be empty or not logically.  But I am aware of this workaround.

---

Here is a minimum verifiable example of the issue:

---

The minimum verifiable example:

```
#! /bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    test(x)
}

function test(x,   y){
    y = length(x)
    x[1] = 1            # <- fatal: attempt to use scalar parameter as an array
}
```

---

Meanwhile, this works:

```
#! /bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    test(x)
}

function test(x,   y){
    #  y = length(x)
    x[1] = 1            # <- now it works
}
```

---

What I need to do is be able to access the length of the un-initialized variable (because, in the recursion, it will generally be initialized, but the first time, it will not be) without forcing it to be a scalar type.  I am aware of a work-around where I store a "length" index in the array.

How do I accomplish this functionality within awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    test(x)
    print "done"
}

function test(x,   y,i){
    for (i in x) {
        ++y
    }
    x[y+1] = 1
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
done
```

By using an array operator (`in`) on `x` I am telling awk that `x` IS an array and so if it was never typed before (what you're referring to as uninitialized) then it will be typed as an array at that point.

Using `length()` wasn't helping you since it can be called on both strings and arrays and it's arg is assumed to be a string by default so calling it was typing `x` as a string. Using `isarray()` would only recognize `x` as an array AFTER `x` is typed to be an array, first time through it, just like length(), `isarray(x)` would type `x` to be a string since it can take either type of arg.

Comment: interesting! even after `x[y+1]` statement `length(x)` fails in the function body; some quirk I guess.